# Multi functional Admin Panel, Need Clarificatoin

Tags: asp.net, architecture, development-environment, html

I started working on a website which has admin panel, contains many admin activities. Consider for example

Admin can do followings:

- Manage His/Her profile
- Can Upload files
- Manages user uploaded files
- Assign some ratings to user
- Calculate Income etc.

In such scenario, each one of the above contains many sub activities. say "Upload files" activity has many sub activities like "Listing Files", "Suspended Files", "Spam files" etc. and "Assign some ratings to user" has many sub activities like "Top rated users", "No rated", "Grooming users" etc.

Here, I'm Considering and storing each and every main and sub activities in "Activity" table and assigning **Activities to a "Role"** and **"Role" to "User"**. Once assigned is done; based on logged-in **User's Role** I'm displaying activity list as a Menu

Here, I need a clarification of development architecture. Which one is best option from the followings:

1. Creating a separate web page (.aspx) for each Activity, and browse that page based activity selection. say If I select "File list from a menu" It should browse **"FileList.aspx"** later this file will be extended with parameters like **FileList.aspx?doc=msword** etc.
2. Creating a separate webpage for group of Activities. say **"Files.aspx"** which contains many panels for each sub-activities. So every time I need to switch a particular panel from this page based on Activity request.
3. Creating a Single web page with many panels. each panel represents a activity.

I don't know which to follow, Are these are best approaches? If yes, which one? If not suggest me something so I can start with best one

Comment: I would go for 1. 2 is a programming push. And definitely NOT 3. Other than that, it looks like you listed the best approaches.

Comment: +1 for point 1, is the simplest. And normally simplest is the best

Comment: @NewAmbition fine, Many guys are saying that putting many panels inside a webpage and switching them using code will give bad performance (In-case of option 2 and 3) if website has many online user visits. Is First one is ok for this issue?

Comment: @MVC3Seeker Yes Putting many panels inside a web page and switching them based on code will reduce the performance.

Comment: @MVC3Seeker, yes, the first option is perfect.